# Why am I getting Fragment not Attached to Activity Error?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a thread which triggers a callback method in my Activity which has a fragment. The Activity then calls a method within the Fragment to refresh the UI with new info. In that method, getString() is called.  When getstring() is called, I get a 'Fragment not Attached to Activity error'.  This UI refreshing error is guarded runOnUIThread. The fragment is added like so:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(fragmentContainerID, fragment, tag)
            .commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

The activity uses two different layout files for horizontal and vertical orientation. Their are two fragment containers in both layouts. They have the same names in both horizontal and vertical layouts, but they do not match each other. The fragments are added using the above code the first time the Activity is created. On orientation changes, the fragments are automatically added into the layouts because the fragment containers have the same ids in both vertical and horizontal orientation.
When the savedInstanceState is not null, I get a reference to the fragments by using

```
fm.findFragmentByTag
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ? The fragments are visibly added to the Activity perfectly fine, and several minutes go by before this thread callback occurs, so I don't see how the Fragment is not "attached".

EDIT:  Sigh, after some debugging Ive found that adding fragments in this way is perfectly fine. Code elsewhere in the Activity ( I registered for a callback twice) caused my fragment not attached error. If anyone reading this is getting this error, keep in mind that this issue can be triggered from elsewhere. Also, you have to setRetainInstance to true in the fragment to avoid it being recreated. Tags alone don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are added one-per-container so if you are using `.add(fragmentContainerID, fragment, tag)` ensure firstly that `fragmentContainerID` is different for each of the fragments added.

However, these sorts of issue are most often caused by a misunderstanding in how orientation changes are handled. When you change orientation and let the oncreate handle the adding: *you get a new fragment of the same type* what this means is that if your background task has a reference to your fragment - it has a reference to the *old* (now detached) fragment. What you need to do is to make sure the same fragment gets added to the tag (not a new instance). To do that just don't (re)create a fragment instance when we are only restoring state

```
public class MyActivity ... {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        frag.setArguments( getIntent().getExtras() ); //if it takes params
        fm.beginTransaction().add(fragmentContainerID, frag, tag).commit();
    }

    //after this point a call to MyFragment frag = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag); should always return the correct fragment
}
```

It's probably also a wise idea for your task to look for the fragment right when it does its callback to update the UI (and NOT to hold on to a reference to it). Depending on how you've set up your task it just means changing from `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();` then the task is created, to calling it as part of the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Hi sorry, I realized my language was not very clear. I was typing in a hurry, sorry. The problem is, I am doing exactly what you are describing. The background task does not have a reference to the fragment , the activity does. And it is getting the references to that fragment in the exact way you described.  The two fragment containers have different ids . But there is a horizontal layout for the entire activity and an entirely different vertical layout and in both of those files, the fragment containers have the  still have the same ids.

Answer (score 0):

When change orientation, fragment automatically added to FragmentManager and forget own tag!!

Use this code to find your fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments())
{
    if(fragment instanceof MyFragment)
        myFragment = (MyFragment)fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you find the fragments on orientation change, try detaching them and then reattaching them before any operation.  Or if that does not work  remove them and add them.  then continue.....   I have even had to sometimes put a time delay of a few millisec after detach and before attach to ensure all OK.